# VM shut down, website unreachable

Tags: apache-2.2, google-compute-engine

I just noticed one of my websites at http://kaboodle.io has shut down.

Machine was off for about twelve hours for unknown reasons
[image]

Apache2 is running, instance group was empty so I added again my vm instance (why was it removed?). Restarted VM too, site still unreachable.

Completely confused at to what happened. Help please!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one outside of Google Support can help you answer this question.

Comment: Google doesn't have support so I was kind hoping I wasn't the only who that happened to @EEAA

Comment: They absolutely do have support. Perhaps you just aren't subscribed to a support plan.

Comment: @EEAA They have support starting at $150/month, I was hoping not to have to go down that road.

Comment: Plain and simple, there is no way anyone other than Google can tell you what happened to your VM.

Comment: @Anustart, if you assign an ephemeral IP address to your VM instance, after the restart the IP address can be changed. Make sure the kaboodle.io is pointing to the new IP address of your VM machine. If this is the case, I recommend using a static IP address for your web server.

Comment: @Kamran Thank you so much, that was it. Such weird behaviours on GCE, I think I might take my business somewhere else.

Comment: @EEAA Somebody told me what happened....

Comment: @Callombert AWS - and virtually every other cloud host - does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To add visibility posting an answer:

As per Kamran's comment GCE VMs can have static or ephemeral [external IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#externaladdresses). "Ephemeral external IP addresses are available to VM instances and forwarding rules. Ephemeral external IP address remain attached to a VM instance only until the VM is stopped and restarted or the instance is terminated." Since the IP changed the domain name needed to be pointed to the new IP address.

Static external IP addresses are only [charged](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) if they are not being used.